# Is there any point in me voting to delete answers?

Tags: support

"Not an answer" answers are often quickly flagged for mods to deal with, and that works fine.

The "trusted user" privilege appears to exist largely to alleviate some of the load from the mods, by allowing users to vote on more things, for example deleting answers because they are "not answers".

Currently, besides the mods, there's only two users with this privilege though.
My guess is, this means we can't actually use the vote system, yet, for this purpose.

So does me using it make any sense?

Comment: NAA and (A)VLQ are the most time consuming to deal with.  Very often NAA is very clear, but there are a lot of incorrect NAA and VLQ flags, and these take time to deal with.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @MPD I guess I don't understand what happens to these votes, and because of that I don't see how it helps that I do vote. Short of at least 5, or ideally 9 voters, how does it help?

Comment: AFAIK, they don't show up on any of the mod tool pages, but you do see them when you visit the question.  So, diamond mods may see these delete votes when they are processing flags that usually come up on it.  It can help swing the decision when it is a borderline post.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct: We don't have enough users with the privilege of voting to delete a post, to avoid diamond moderators chime in to delete a post.
It could seem that voting to delete a post doesn't have the effect of taking out the burden from moderators, but it is not so. The alternative would be, for example, flagging an answer as *not an answer*. This would make the moderators check out if the answer is a comment, another question, or just *thanks* for a given answer. Contrary, your vote to delete a post is explicitly telling the moderators that you think the post is bad enough to be delete. Plus, since you are a 20K user, I trust you know the difference between a wrong answer, and something else written as answer.

So, definitively, your votes to delete posts are welcome, as they do help the moderators.